# Densest Sub Graph and forbidden Pairs

Tags: combinatorics, subgraphs, independent-sets

Given two graphs $G$ and $F$ on the same vertex set $V$. Compute a sub set $\tilde{V}\subset V$ which' sub graph of $G$ is of maximum density and does not have any pair that is connected in $F$.

Formally, find

$$
arg\max_{\tilde{V}\subset V}\Bigg\{\frac{\big\vert {E(G)}_{\vert\tilde{V}}\big\vert}{\vert \tilde{V}\vert} \,\,\Bigg\vert\,\, (v, v^{\prime})\notin E(F)\forall v, v^{\prime}\in\tilde{V}  \Bigg\}
$$.

So, we could compute maximum independent sets of $F$ and compute for each its densest sub graph. This may not yield a desired node set. Looks like we want 'high overlaps' between $G$-density and $F$-independency.

Is there a method to solve this or some ideas on how to combine densest-sub-graph-algorithm and maximum-independence-set-algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard.  (It is at least as hard as maximum independent set, which can be seen by setting $G$ to be the fully connected graph.)

Therefore, a reasonable approach is to use an off-the-shelf ILP solver.  Introduce zero-or-one variables $x_{v}$, with the intended meaning that $x_v=1$ means that $v \in \tilde{V}$.  Define $y_{u,v} := x_u \land x_v$.  Introduce a new (real-valued) unknown $d$ to represent the density.  Then you can encode all of the requirements via the following linear inequalities:

- The density is at least $d$: i.e., $\sum_{u,v} y_{u,v} \ge d \sum_v x_v$.
- The $y$'s are consistent with the $x$'s: i.e., $y_{u,v} \ge x_u + x_v - 1$, $y_{u,v} \le x_u$, $y_{u,v} \le x_v$.
- There is no pair that is connected in $F$: i.e., $y_{u,v}=0$ for all $(u,v) \in E(F)$.

Finally, ask the ILP solver to maximize $d$, subject to the above linear inequalities.

Alternatively, you could use a SAT solver together with a pseudo-boolean constraint to represent the constraint on the density, and use binary search over $d$.

Comment: Excellent and complete answer,  thanks so much @D.W.! I really like it and will try MIP solver. Could try it through z3-solver for the smt variation, this will probably be much slower.